# Why does the app compiles even there are "unresolved references" and why Android Studio didn´t recognize it until I found the unresolved reference?

Tags: java, android

Why sometimes you have to move from java file to java file to see if there is an "unresolved reference"? I mean, when I compiled my app at the first time there were 0 Project Errors in the "Problems" section. Later I decidied to open some java files/classes and I discovered that there was a reference highlighted in red (unresolved reference), I compiled the app again and surprise, now there was 1 Project Error that was this inresolved reference. Why didn`t the app reported this "unresolved reference" at the first time and I had to move from java file to java file to search for this unresolved reference myself? I don´t know why this is not done automatically by Android Studio. And why does the app compile even I have this unresolved reference? The unresolved reference was a R.styleable that I forgot to set the format of it in the attrs.xml file.

Comment: The R class(es) are generated by gradle/Android Studio. By opening certain layouts, activities or fragments Android Studio may have updated the R file(s) and thus the error was introduced.

Comment: @Robert okay, that could explain that the error was introduced when opening an activity. But what can explain that the app compliles fine although there are "unresolved reference" project errors?